# In my page heading and drop-down is showing different in chrome and Firefox even though CSS and HTML both are same for both browsers

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I am having a page in which heading and drop-down both are inline but that page looks different in Chrome and Firefox even though HTML and CSS classes are same, there is no specific css or style used for a specific browser.

heading is not in center in chrome , but in Firefox heading is in the center and drop-down is in right without any space.

Following CSS

```
.h2 {
    padding: 9px 7px;
    margin: 0;
    color: #2b6dd1;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 25% !important;
}
```

I wants heading in center and drop down in right in both the browsers chrome as well as Firefox.

Please remember the I used searchable drop-down .

Comment: Please add the relevant html

Comment: Please also share the HTML and replicate your example in a snippet. Otherwise we cannot help. Also, why use `margin-left:25%` ? and why use `!important` ? :)

Answer (score 0):

They are diferent web navigators so they dont read the code the same way, you must add some prefixes to make your code readable for all of them.

```
-webkit //chrome
-moz- //firefox
-o- //Opera
-mz- //Internet Explorer
```

The most common web navigator is google chrome, because it works better and has more functionalities (I´ve worked with Chrome and Edge and I recommend Chrome).

I leave you a link here to a web [where](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/WebKit_Extensions) u can learn more about this